# How to handle / model "cost of provided spare parts per PO line item" where one spare qty is divided between multiple line items? / Postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, database-design, normalization, business-intelligence

**Problem**

My objective is to help improve the data modeling / handling of my company’s present cost-of-goods [‘COGS’] calculation.

Everything in the current Postgres 11 table structure is pretty standard, and the calculations easy, *except for one thing:*  Most purchase orders include line items ‘A’ intended as spares for other line items ‘B’  and ‘C’ on the same order, and whose cost is intended to be factored into the cost of ‘B’ and ‘C’, which means that the cost of ‘A’ must be divided up among ‘B’ and ‘C’ proportional to the quantities of ‘B’ and ‘C.’

Of key consideration for the design of the tables is that suppliers routinely ship incomplete quantities [with respect to total quantity on purchase order], and that suppliers routinely ship items from multiple POs in the same shipment.

A typical purchase order invoice looks something like this :

```
  sku          qty     each     line_item_cost 
----------------------------------------------
  product_B    200       50         10000
  product_C    400       75         30000
  spare_A      600        5          3000
  shipping       1     2000          2000
```

where ‘spare_A’ is a part for both ‘product_B’ and ‘product_C’ ; in the above example, 2000 of ‘spare_A’ cost should be applied to ‘product_C’ and 1000 to ‘product_A’.

Naturally, I’d like to represent this data as cleanly as possible.

I’m having a real tough time with this problem, and nothing analogous has turned up in my searches here / on SO, nor in my copies of *SQL Cookbook*  and *The Data Warehousing Toolkit*.

**Current table structure**

The current tables involved in this cost-of-goods operation are :

`orders`

`order_items`

`payments` [this records wire transfers, etc]

`product_allocations` [this records dollar amounts allocated to product line items on POs]

`shipment_allocations` [this records dollar amounts allocated to shipping and handling costs]

`shipments` [carrier ID, tracking, total ship cost, etc]

`shipment_items` [actual items within shipments],

The problematic table is `order_items`, wherein the aforementioned spare parts lines appear. Here’s the definition of that table with the problematic column noted in comments :

```
CREATE TABLE order_items (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  created_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
  name TEXT , /*this is an identifier which combines SKU and PO# info */,
  order_invoice TEXT REFERENCES orders.order_invoice, 
  sku TEXT, 
  uses_spare TEXT REFERENCES order_items.name, /* because each spare is also an order item */
  spare_of TEXT[], /*this is the “problem column.”  Currently a 1d array so that it can hold multiple values which are drawn from this table’s “sku” column */ 
  unit_cost NUMERIC(19,2),
  quantity INT, 
  product_allocations TEXT REFERENCES product_allocations.name,  /*records cost allocation*/ 
);
```

Currently, the cost of the spares is allocated by a function that considers the spares line item qty and cost, and divides it among the line items referenced in that record's `spares_of` column, proportionally with their respective quantities.

My gut tells me there must be a more optimal way to represent this “spare goes to multiple items” information.

One option considered was to make `spares` a separate table and have each spare-instance<->sku-instance relationship represented there and referred back to `order_items`, but this was decided against [however, if this is the best way, I’d like to know that].

### Summary

What is the best way to represent the above-described relationship, i.e., the cost of a single `spare_of` record being associated with multiple `sku` line items, with the overall goal of producing an accurate and easily-reportable cost-of-goods (COGS)?

Comment: this looks like an accounting question  and looking at the notes on the create table the database was originally very poorly laid out for analyze at a latter date.    questions regarding a few things and comments  1: COGS and Inventory are not the same thing  COGS is for non-inventory items that are expensed that accounting period,  or its inventory that has been sold in a period,  2:allocations is a SO, or some kind of WIP operations which is it?   SPARE suggest BOM of some kind exist.  All this stuff in typically broken out is lots tables to easy tracking and reporting. explain SPARE better

Comment: I'll answer your questions as best I can [I'm not an accountant by any stretch] : 1) In  this case, the COGS for a given item is derived quarterly from unit + shipping + handling costs (exclusive of labor), which can differ per purchase order; I don't quite understand your question about allocations, but in this context, the word refers to a portion of a payment that is allocated to a certain expense [in this case, product and shipping]; 'spare'  is like a spare part for an item - no formal BOM exists but if it did, a spare for an order item would appear on that order item's BOM - thanks!

Comment: p.s. @zsheep I'm eager to hear any suggestions for revision of the table structure; this project is not set in stone and I may be able to introduce improvements if applicable

Comment: this needs to be completely broken out differently as different types of transactions are being intermixed.  appears PO (purchase order) is  being treated as WO workorder.  which normally is used to merge raw material, machine operations and labor into a new product  that is sold which applies to manufacturing,  if this application is for Construction business, how raw material labor and freight cost  are rolled up are done differently.  if this is Project/construction managment app again this done different.  But based on information thus far this is NOT GAP (general accepted practices)

Comment: out of room  Spare parts are treated as inventory the asset side of the P&L and not recorded in COGS unless its none inventory  or expensed.  these spare parts should be in Inventory table keeping track what is on hand and its value.  you need to tell more how this app actually works and the industry its used in

Comment: @zsheep I sure appreciate your detailed consideration of my question!  The business is consumer durable goods; the organization doesn't create work orders as such, but they have expressed to me that they do wish the cost of spare parts to be rolled into the applicable product cost [I've made note of your suggestion and will raise it at the next opportunity.  The application itself and its tables are separate from the main BI and transaction schemas and in short, the person issuing the PO records this info + updates on invoice receipt, and the person in charge of costing later derives the cost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103316/discussion-between-mister-october-and-zsheep).